# print the last line of a loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

What I'm trying to do is print the results in increments of 5 - DONE. Then, print only the last line of the loop. For ex: if z=26, print results of z @ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25. Then println with z @ 26. I'm stuck and can't figure it out.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= z; i++) {
    b = b + (b * y) + x + w;

    if (i % 5 == 0)
        //input 1
        System.out.println("In " + i + " years, IRA value: " + b);          

    //input 2 - value of IRA when retirement is reached
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: What does it output now?

Comment: No output yet. I don't know how to output it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what initial values `b`, `x`, `w` and `y` got so I just initialized them somehow ..

But I think you want something like this:

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

        int z = 26;
        int b = 0;
        int x = 1;
        int w = 2;
        int y = 1;

        for (int i = 1;i<=z;i++) {
            b = b+(b*y)+x+w;
            if (i % 5 == 0)
                System.out.println("In " + i + " years, IRA value: " + b);          
        }

        System.out.print(z);
     }
}
```

Output:

```
In 5 years, IRA value: 93
In 10 years, IRA value: 3069
In 15 years, IRA value: 98301
In 20 years, IRA value: 3145725
In 25 years, IRA value: 100663293
26
```

Comment: Yes, exactly what I want. I didn't paste the whole code. Thanks much everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Change your condition to

```
if(i%5==0 || i==z)
```

Comment: Hi @shmosel. Don't forget that what may be obvious to you, might not be obvious to the many newbies on Stack Overflow. It's always a good idea to explain why your solution solves the problem.

Comment: I thought OP wanted to print the same output for every 5th `z`, as well as for the last value. Anyone who understands `i%5==0` should understand `i==z`. Looks like someone else had the [same idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24253881/1553851).

Answer (score 0):

Adding an or (|| i==z) in the if will do the work

```
for (int i = 1;i<=z;i++) {
    b = b+(b*y)+x+w;
    if (i%5==0 || i==z)

    //input 1
    System.out.println("In " + i + " years, IRA value: " + b);          

    //input 2 - value of IRA when retirement is reached
    System.out.println();

    //end
}
```